# How to add a prefix to a cell that the user can't delete but they can add data behind the prefix

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want every cell to start with PB22 but want the user to add only the random value behind PB22 without deleting the PB22.
Column A
PB2200003
PB2200025
PB2201295

Thanks for any info you can provide :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the CONCAT function. In Col 1 enter PB2, Leave Col 2 for user value. In Col 3 use formula =CONCAT(Col1, Col2). Then Col 3 will display the new value. You can hide Col 1 so users won't be able to change the value.

[CONCAT formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhLao.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to adjust the "numeric" formatting of the cell.

Custom number formatting can format even text strings, so it's not entirely perfectly named. You seem to expect only numeric input, so that wouldn't be needed, but could be done. Use a Custom Format like:

```
"PB22"0;"PB22"-0;"PB22"0;"PB22"@
```

This adds the "PB22" to the beginning of the number they will enter. It would add it even to text they enter.

For the examples you give, this will do nicely. There will be no way at all for them to casually wipe it out or change it. They can do it on purpose, with easy steps, but they can't do it by accident or by "accident." Not at all.

Caveats:

1. The actual value is still what they enter. So entering "1234" gives a DISPLAY of "PB221234" but only "1234" is actually there. All good for what you ask for. But if someone wanted to use the entered value and wished the "PB22" to be part of what they take from the cell, they would have to add that in where they use the value as only "1234" would be taken from the cell. On the other hand, this can be a strength as if they do not want that prefix for their use, it isn't actually there so they don't have to remove it in their formula which simplifies their task.
2. If they enter the prefix themselves, it will certainly look odd... "PB22PB221234" being an example. That would be the case as well with most other ways to do this including you building the string like in `R0E`'s answer. But people do what people do so it's a consideration.
3. If there are other prefixes you want to use, it gets... messy... quickly. You'll have to change formatting strings to keep up with things. But this is an issue for other methods as well (see 2., above).

So, like most things, it comes down to how you want to approach it and what your spreadsheet and how people are going to use it allow.